# How does the interpretive program(ex:perl,shell) work

Tags: shell, perl

I propose a hypothesis: 1. the operating system creates a process space to start the interpreter; 2. the interpreter creates a new process space to start the program that needs to be interpreted, translating the first statement into machine language; 3. the execution of the first statement ends and interrupts; 4. the interpreter translates the next statement and dynamically modifies and creates new instructions.  Well, I can't make it up. I can't understand the concept of explaining and executing.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  do some search and reading, you will find it easy.  And this is out of scope on SO.

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) page for Interpreters. Also, [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.2582&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper in addition provides a comparison of a few interpreters of it's time. It may help you to resolve your query.

Comment: When you run a Perl program, the compiler first compiles the source code and then executes it. That would seem, to me, to make Perl more of a compiled language than an interpreted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a example interpreter:

```
while (<>) {
   my ($cmd, @args) = split;
   if    ($cmd eq '...') { ... }
   elsif ($cmd eq '...') { ... }
   elsif ($cmd eq '...') { ... }
   else                  { ... }
}
```

This points out that the interpreted program isn't run in a separate process from the interpreter.

This also points out there isn't necessarily any translation to machine language.

---

Due note that Perl is a compiled language rather than interpreted one.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'print("Hello, world!\n");'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[PV "Hello, world!\n"] s
5  <@> print vK
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

That said, the compiled form is not native instructions. There are different ways this can be handled, but Perl effectively interprets these. The following is that interpreter:

```c
int
Perl_runops_standard(pTHX)
{
    OP *op = PL_op;
    PERL_DTRACE_PROBE_OP(op);
    while ((PL_op = op = op->op_ppaddr(aTHX))) {
        PERL_DTRACE_PROBE_OP(op);
    }
    PERL_ASYNC_CHECK();

    TAINT_NOT;
    return 0;
}
```

(Copied from [here](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/44523d1ffde5f23de2e13216cdbac46357631904:/run.c).)

The ops are really data structures arranged in a linked list (with other pointers for jumps) rather than a stream of bytes encoding instructions. The above loop traverses the list, executing the function associated with each op. These function returns the address of the next op to execute, thus forming the program.

Some languages probably take a similar approach. Other languages definitely take a different approach.